# $on,$once is not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

Scenario is,
im using following versions of angularFire and firebase in my project in index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.9.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

and angular.min.js is installed locally. IM not using AngularJS from CDN.

When I try to use $on,$once functions in my Angular project it gives me error that $on is not defined... and I am also facing error of dependency injection for using $firebaseArray,$firebaseObject even I declare firebase in my module. Here is Module declaration in my App.js file which main file and all of my controlles are in this single file

```
var appMainModule = angular.module('appMain', [ 'firebase','ngRoute'])
```

If I upgrade my versions to latest as shown in following links
[(https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)]

Then I face error that firebase has been removed, you may instantiate $firebaseArray,$firebaseObject directly...

Help me to solve my issues,

Comment: How are you using `$on`? It is normally attached with scope: `$scope.$on(name, listener)`

Comment: @austinthedeveloper appMainModule.controller('VictimGetCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', function ($scope, $firebase) {
     var firebaseObj = new Firebase("URL");
     var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj);
     

     $scope.articlesd = sync.$asArray();
     $scope.articlesd.$on('value', function (snapshot) {
         console.log('test method');
     });

Comment: There is no `$firebase` service and there're no `$on` nor `$once` in angularfire.
There are `on` and `once` in native firebase SDK. From the sample code in the comment you are mixing up things a little bit. Checkout the [AngularFire seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed). Also work with the [AngularFire API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)